# How do you do multiple regresson in Excel (to show Mediation)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, templates, regression

Does anyone know how to use Excel to do multiple regession to show full and partial mediation using Baron and Kenny's method and alternatively Preacher and Hayes. I've been looking around for algorithms in R or even Statistica but most of these are blackboxes. If there are any datasets (that can be transferred or are in an .xls file) then it would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two references I could locate,

- [**Sobel Test**](http://people.ku.edu/~preacher/sobel/sobel.htm), [2](http://www.comm.ohio-state.edu/ahayes/sobel.htm)
- [**MedGraph**](http://www.victoria.ac.nz/psyc/staff/paul-jose-files/medgraph/instructions.php)

Comment: @nik thanks for this! I actually read the first site all the time but I haven't seen the MedGraph site :)

Comment: @pageman, I had two different references for Sobel, turns out, i messed up while linking.. just fixed that.